# Optimizing Algorithm for Price of Delivery

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I have a customer who ordered 3 items online.
Then I have a list of store for each item, sorted by cheapest delivery rate.
For example I have 5 stores. Then there is 5^3 = 125 combinations of stores.

So

```
Item 1 - store 1, store 9, store 4, store 3, store 2
Item 2 - store 9, store 10, store 1, store 2, store 5
Item 3 - store 5, store 1, store 4, store 8, store 7
```

So store 1,9,5 have the lowest delivery rate respectively for Items 1, 2, and 3.
But you can see that I can send both Item 1 and 2 from store 9 and store 2, and I can send all three items from store 1.

When sending a package, we might use a box with a certain dimensions, and maybe sending Items 1 and 2 from store 9 will be cheaper than sending Item 1 from store 1 and Item 2 from store 9.

The same applies to store 1. Maybe sending all 3 items from store 1 in a box will be cheaper than sending them separately from stores 1, 9, and 5.

Right now I am thinking about checking the box delivery rate of all the stores that contains 2 or more items and trying to determine the lowest price.

Know that sometime the customer can order more than 10 items and the number of combinations will then be 5^10+ which is huge.

I am wondering if there is any quicker way to find the best price.

Comment: Please provide code. Otherwise this is just an algorithm question.

Comment: Sorry, I changed to Algorithm, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is using integer programming, defining two sets of variables.

The first set of variables would be binary variables that indicate whether an item is sent from a particular store. In your example, there would be 15 such binary variables, one for each item-store pairing. We can call the binary variable for item i and store s `x_is`.

The other set of variables would be a binary indicator for whether we ship any items from store `s`. In your example, there would be 9 such binary variables (you have stores 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, and 10). We can call the binary variable for store s `y_s`.

Then you would need to add constraints that make sure that an item i is sent from a store s (aka `x_is = 1`) only when we ship from that store (aka `y_s = 1`). You can do this by adding a constraint `x_is <= y_s` for all items i and stores s.

Now you can build an objective that separately indicates the cost of providing an item i from store x (these are the coefficients on the `x_is` variables) and the cost of shipping a package from store `s` (these are the coefficients on the `y_s` variables). Your goal would be to minimize this objective.

You can solve these models using any number of different programming languages. One of the simplest might by the Excel Solver package, though there are integer programming solvers in all major programming languages.